# How to change database connection on the fly for PhpUnit tests

Tags: php, unit-testing, magento, phpunit

I am working on a Magento 1.4.1 project, and I want to use PhpUnit to test my models.

I am able to run my PhpUnit test using the default connection, but I want to use a different database connection than the one I use to test the interface.

What I would like to know (if its possible):

1. Is there a way to select a different
   connection for my models before I
   run all my tests;
2. Can I just add a
   connection in my local.xml like
   this:

   ```
       <phpunit_setup>
           <connection>
               <host><![CDATA[localhost]]></host>
               <username><![CDATA[username]]></username>
               <password><![CDATA[password]]></password>
               <dbname><![CDATA[dbname]]></dbname>
               <active>1</active>
           </connection>
       </phpunit_setup>
   ```

   if yes, how do I access it.

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe there is another solution, but I found out that we can change the "etc_dir" when we lauch the application.

1. I copied the "app/etc/local.xml" and "app/etc/config.xml" to a newly created folder "tests/etc/";
2. I changed this database configuration to what I needed;
3. I made a symbolic link in "tests/etc/" to point to "app/etc/modules" (A copy is not recommended);
4. Finally I passed the defaults parameters and the "etc_dir" to the "Mage::app()" method in a file "tests/helper.php" that is executed to setup my tests (include path, white list for code coverage).

It looked like this.

Before
"tests/helper.php"

```
...
// Start Magento application
Mage::app();
...
```

After
"tests/helper.php"

```
...
// Start Magento application
Mage::app('default', 'store', '/path/to/test/etc');
...
```

My app folder

[image]

My test folder

[image]

Hope this could help someone.

Answer (score 1):

You can just create your own local.xml, for example:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <global>
        <resources>
            <default_setup>
                <connection>
                    <host><![CDATA[localhost]]></host>
                    <username><![CDATA[root]]></username>
                    <password></password>
                    <dbname><![CDATA[magento_test]]></dbname>
                    <active>1</active>
                </connection>
            </default_setup>
        </resources>
    </global>
</config>
```

And apply it in you testCase setUp method with:

```
$test_config = new Mage_Core_Model_Config('test/local.xml');
Mage::getConfig()->extend($test_config);
```